# Increase DBUS max_replies_per_connection

Tags: dbus, cockpit

I am using cockpit on ubuntu server 22.04 and when I try to load all the services I see the following error: "Loading unit failed: The maximum number of pending replies per connection has been reached"

If I take a look in /var/log/syslog I see the following error:

```
[system] The maximum number of pending replies for ":1.273" (uid=0 pid=71384 comm="cockpit-bridge --privileged " label="unconfined") has been reached (max_replies_per_connection=128)]
```

I took a look at the documentation for dbus-daemon: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/dbus-daemon.1.html and it looks like I should be setting the new limit in /usr/share/dbus-1/system-local.conf. However this does not seem to be working. I also changed the corresponding line directly in /usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf to 50000.

```
$ cat system-local.conf

<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-Bus Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>
</busconfig>
```

I searched the entire PC for references to 'max_replies_per_connection' and the only places I see 128 are in /snap/.... but AFAIK Cockpit is installed with apt so I don't see how this would be relevant.

```
$ rg max_replies_per -g '!/data' -g '!/databackup' -g '!/mnt' -g '!/media' -g '!/run' -g '!/proc' -g '!/home' -g '!/var/log' 2> /dev/null
snap/core/15419/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
79:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

snap/core18/2785/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf
127:  <!-- <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">128</limit> -->

snap/core18/2785/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
79:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

snap/core/14946/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
79:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

snap/core20/1950/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf
127:  <!-- <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">128</limit> -->

snap/core20/1950/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
79:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

snap/core20/1891/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf
127:  <!-- <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">128</limit> -->

snap/core20/1891/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
79:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

snap/core18/2751/usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf
127:  <!-- <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">128</limit> -->

snap/core18/2751/usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
79:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

usr/share/defaults/at-spi2/accessibility.conf
33:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

usr/share/dbus-1/session.conf
79:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>

usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf
127:  <!-- <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit> -->

usr/share/dbus-1/system-local.conf
4:  <limit name="max_replies_per_connection">50000</limit>
```

I also tried rebooting the server after these changes to no avail. My question is how can I override the max_replies_per_connection limit on Ubuntu 22.04

Edit: I also updated the systemd file for dbus.service to explicitely use --config-file and got the below error indicating dbus is being started with the modified config file:

```
Jun 27 15:07:28 falcon dbus-daemon[1648426]: --config-file specified but configuration file /usr/share/dbus-1/system.conf already requested
```